# I need a better way to reduce the line of codes which has a lot of if statements with method calls in conditions

Tags: java, if-statement

This is my code , I need to know if there is any way to reduce the number of lines in the program.

Since there is method calls involved in the if statements I cannot use enum to replace them.

```
public class AgreementQueryBuilder {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static String searchQueryBuilder(FetchAgreementsModel agreementsModel,
            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") List obj) {

        StringBuilder selectQuery = new StringBuilder(
                "select *,e.id as agreementid from eglams_agreement e left outer join eglams_rentincrementtype  t on e.rent_increment_method=t.id where");

        // if statement to check the arguments and build the where criteria

        if (agreementsModel.getAgreementId() != null || agreementsModel.getAgreementNumber() != null
                || agreementsModel.getStatus() != null || agreementsModel.getTenantId() != null
                || (agreementsModel.getFromDate() != null && agreementsModel.getToDate() != null)
                || agreementsModel.getTenderNumber() != null || agreementsModel.getTinNumber() != null
                || agreementsModel.getTradeLicense_number() != null)
            return null;

        boolean isAllFieldsNull = true;

        if (agreementsModel.getAgreementId() != null) {
            if (isAllFieldsNull == true) {
                selectQuery.append(" e.id=?");
                isAllFieldsNull = false;
                obj.add(agreementsModel.getAgreementId());
            }
        }

        if (agreementsModel.getAgreementNumber() != null) {
            if (isAllFieldsNull == true) {
                selectQuery.append(" e.agreement_number=?");
                isAllFieldsNull = false;
            } else
                selectQuery.append(" and e.agreement_number=?");
            obj.add(agreementsModel.getAgreementNumber());
        }

        if (agreementsModel.getStatus() != null) {

            if (isAllFieldsNull == true) {
                selectQuery.append(" e.status=?");
                isAllFieldsNull = false;
            } else
                selectQuery.append(" and e.status=?");

            obj.add(agreementsModel.getStatus());
        }

        if (agreementsModel.getTenantId() != null) {
            if (isAllFieldsNull == true) {
                selectQuery.append(" e.tenant_id=?");
                isAllFieldsNull = false;
            } else
                selectQuery.append(" and e.tenant_id=?");

            obj.add(agreementsModel.getTenantId());
        }

        if (agreementsModel.getTenderNumber() != null) {
            if (isAllFieldsNull == true) {
                selectQuery.append(" e.tender_number=?");
                isAllFieldsNull = false;
            } else
                selectQuery.append(" and e.tender_number=?");
            obj.add(agreementsModel.getTenderNumber());
        }
        if (agreementsModel.getTinNumber() != null) {
            if (isAllFieldsNull == true) {
                selectQuery.append(" e.tin_number=?");
                isAllFieldsNull = false;
            } else
                selectQuery.append(" and e.tin_number=?");
            obj.add(agreementsModel.getTinNumber());
        }

        if (agreementsModel.getTradeLicense_number() != null) {
            if (isAllFieldsNull == true) {
                selectQuery.append(" e.TradeLicense_number=?");
                isAllFieldsNull = false;
            } else
                selectQuery.append(" and e.TradeLicense_number=?");
            obj.add(agreementsModel.getTradeLicense_number());
        }

        if (agreementsModel.getFromDate() != null) {
            if (agreementsModel.getToDate() != null) {
                if (isAllFieldsNull == true) {
                    selectQuery.append(" t.FromDate=?");
                    isAllFieldsNull = false;
                } else
                    selectQuery.append(" and t.FromDate=?");

                obj.add(agreementsModel.getFromDate());
                selectQuery.append(" and t.ToDate=?");
                obj.add(agreementsModel.getToDate());
            }
        }
        System.err.println(selectQuery);
        return selectQuery.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It seems that your code currently works, and you are looking to improve it. Generally these questions are too opinionated for this site, but you might find better luck at [CodeReview.SE](//codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their requirements](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are a bit more strict than this site.

Comment: Put all of your where clauses into a list; join them with `" and "` at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Look at your code:

```
if (agreementsModel.getAgreementId() != null ||  ... )
    return null;
```

So we know that if `getAgreementId() != null` this method will return null and will not go any further. But right after that you write:

```
if (agreementsModel.getAgreementId() != null) {
        selectQuery.append(" e.id=?");
        isAllFieldsNull = false;
        obj.add(agreementsModel.getAgreementId());
    }
}
```

We know that this entire block can never be entered, because if `getAgreementId() != null` was true, the method would have already returned.

So, the short answer to your question is yes, you can make this code much shorter by removing all of the irrelevant blocks of code that will never be called.

The long answer is that you should fix and debug your code to ensure that it actually does what you expect it to do before worrying about whether you can make it shorter. I suspect that means that this `if` can be removed since it makes all the following blocks useless:

```
if (agreementsModel.getAgreementId() != null || agreementsModel.getAgreementNumber() != null
            || agreementsModel.getStatus() != null || agreementsModel.getTenantId() != null
            || (agreementsModel.getFromDate() != null && agreementsModel.getToDate() != null)
            || agreementsModel.getTenderNumber() != null || agreementsModel.getTinNumber() != null
            || agreementsModel.getTradeLicense_number() != null)
        return null;
```

But only you can know how your code should work. I suggest testing it to make sure it works before asking how to make it shorter.

Answer (score 1):

I saw that the conditional used to generate an SQL Query. I believe you should change this to more readable, shorter and maintainable code using mapper framework like [MyBatis](http://www.mybatis.org/) / [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/).

Sample of query with conditional using [Mybatis](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html) below :

```
<select id="findActiveBlogLike" resultType="Blog">
   SELECT * FROM BLOG WHERE state = ‘ACTIVE’
     <if test="title != null">
        AND title like #{title}
     </if>
     <if test="author != null and author.name != null">
        AND author_name like #{author.name}
     </if>
     <!-- add another conditional to add extra filter --> 
</select>
```

On the sample above, we can dynamically generate a query by checking the input bean Blog. If title not null, add title in the criteria,and if authoer is not null, also add author to the criteria, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Your code all follows the same pattern

```
if (agreementsModel.getAgreementNumber() != null) {
  if (isAllFieldsNull == true) {
    selectQuery.append(" e.agreement_number=?");
    isAllFieldsNull = false;
  } else
    selectQuery.append(" and e.agreement_number=?");

      obj.add(agreementsModel.getAgreementNumber());
}
```

Which is: if something isn't null, put that thing in a list; and append a string based on some flag; then set the flag to true.

You can write this as a method:

```
boolean yourMethod(Object obj, List<Object> objs, String clause, StringBuilder clauses, boolean flag) {
  if (obj == null) return flag;

  objs.add(obj);
  if (!flag) clauses.append(" and ");
  clauses.append(clause);

  return false;
}
```

So, you can now replace the above snippet of your code with:

```
isAllFieldsNull = yourMethod(
    agreementsModel.getAgreementNumber(),
    obj,
    " e.agreement_number=? ",
    selectQuery,
    isAllFieldsNull);
```

etc, for the subsequent fields.